# Can we use Resharper for angular code analysis

Tags: angular, resharper

I am new to Resharper. I have confusions regarding that even after reading docs.
Can we use Resharper for analysis of Angular project or typescript file? If yes, how can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that since ReSharper 2022.2 support of JavaScript and TypeScript is being on pause. That means that it's disabled by default and currently no fixes are provided for the issues. If you still want to try it, you can enable support in ReSharper | Options | Environment | Products & Features.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use resharper for analysis of anguler or typescript code. install a trial version from Visual studio marketplace and try for yourself.